Easy way to replace all keys in a data structure with a standard one
I have a data structure like this one (with many hashes & arrays, containing different environments, users, profiles, access rights etc.) :
%AR = (
'prod' => {
                   'username' => {
                                        'access_profile1' => [
                                                             'accessright1',
                                                             'accessright2',
                                                             'accessright3',
                                                             'accessrightN',
                                                            ],
                                        'access_profile2' => [
                                                             'accessright7',
                                                             'accessright8',
                                                             'accessright9',
                                                            ],
                                        'access_profileN' => [
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                            ],
                                       },
                   },
);

I would like to give my script an option that, when enabled, it must force all profile names with a standard one (e.g. default_profile) in the structure (regenerate it) - of course this would mean that all accessrights are unique otherwise some might override others -
I know that I could do it by simply looping over this structure and filling a "new" structure, like this:
my $newAR;

foreach my $env ( keys %AR ) {
   foreach my $user ( keys %{ $AR{$env} } ) {
      foreach my $profile ( keys %{ $AR{$env}{$user} } ) {

         # fill the new data structure
         foreach my $accessright (@{ $AR{$env}{$user}{$profile} }) {
            push (@{ $newAR{$env}{$user}{'default_profile'} }, $accessright);
         }

      }
   }
}

which at the end gives the correct result:
$VAR1 = {
          'prod' => {
                      'username' => {
                                      'default_profile' => [
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                             'accessrightX',
                                                             'accessright7',
                                                             'accessright8',
                                                             'accessright9',
                                                             'accessright1',
                                                             'accessright2',
                                                             'accessright3',
                                                             'accessrightN'
                                                           ]
                                    }
                    }
        };

Isn't there a "cleaner" way of doing this in Perl?
I am not very strong in all mappings, etc., and I am sure there would be a neater way of writing these nested loops.

print join "\n", map { @$_ } values %{ $AR{'prod'}->{'username'} };

my question is how to regenerate the full data structure (not print values)

There is quite a lot of things you are saying here that does not follow through in your example. You say you want to replace all profile names with a default one, and collect all the accessrights and make them unique. That's not what you are doing, you are just adding all the different accessrights into one, with multiple duplicates. Is your example what you want, or the description?

And also, this looks fairly clean to me. How would you solve this if you did not loop over all the keys?

I indeed was not clear enough, sorry for that. there are NO duplicate accessrights, I just want to "regroup" them all under 1 single profile, in fact.. hope this is clearer. and yes my code works nicely, but I was just under the impression that there would be a "nicer" way to do that in Perl, rather than having these huge nested loops

If this was json and you were using jq, you could use .[][] |= { default_profile: [ .[][] ] }

for ( values %AR ) {
   for my $to_fix ( values %$_ ) {

      %$to_fix = (
         default_profile => [
            map { @$_ }
               values %$to_fix
         ]
      );

   }
}


values %$to_fix returns the array refs.
map { @$_ } … flattens them into access rights.
[ … ] stores them into an array.
%$to_fix = ( default_profile => … ) replaces the existing contents with the new content.


Your code does not place the access rights in any particular order, and neither does mine. Your key names does suggest an order, however. If you want the access rights ordered according to the original key names, you can use something like the following:
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

%$to_fix = (
   default_profile => [
      map { $to_fix->{ $_ }->@* }
         natsort
            keys %$to_fix
   ]
);


Alternatively, it might make more sense to remove duplicate access rights and/or sort them by name.
use List::Util         qw( uniq );
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

%$to_fix = (
   default_profile => [
      natsort              # Sorts the rights. Optional.
         uniq              # Removes duplicates. Optional.
            map { @$_ }
               values %$to_fix
   ]
);


@TLP, Woops! I had tested it, but then I rewrote to be more like OP, and added an extra loop. Fixed.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and give a clear explanation. I see the solution is not  "so simple" but I like it - the first version without sorting - (I rarely use map & values, I always forget about these, I definitely need to play with map more and understand your syntax)
